# Remove metadata from List item with placement.info in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I created two content types, Foods with the containable part, and Colors with the container part. I created a list of colors that contain foods inside them following Bertrand's example here: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/many-ways-to-relate-orchard-things-part-3-lists

Example:
green: avocado, kale, spinach
red: strawberry, raspberry, ketchup

On the page for "green" and "red" I am trying to remove the metadata. I tried this code:

```
<Match ContentType="Food">
    <Match DisplayType="Summary">
        <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
    </Match>
</Match>
```

And the metadata was still there, so I tried this code to make sure I didn't have any typos:

```
<Match ContentType="Food">
    <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
</Match>
```

Again, the metadata was still there for the list view pages, but as expected it did remove the metadata from the display view pages.

I am able to remove the metadata through a `Content-Food.Summary.cshtml` but I know the preferred method is to use the placement.info file.

Is this possible? If not, is it a feature or a bug?

Comment: As a side note about this example: the color should totally be a taxonomy. This is definitely not a job for lists.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy the reason I was thinking of using lists in this case was because I need the foods to be ordered specifically by importance, added and updated regularly. The only way I could figure out to do that with taxonomies would require many queries, widgets, and Vandelay sort order, which seemed like a lot to force a content creator to do. Lists does all of that in a small package. Does that make sense or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes: lists are supposed to implement container/containable relationships, which your example doesn't match. That you need ordering is not a good reason to use the wrong semantics. Content item picker would be better, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much @BertrandLeRoy. This may just be a bad example but your comment is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different views for the Metadata, one for the summary and one for the detail. This is good because it means you can customize how the metadata is displayed in the summary vs the detail, but slightly confusing when you are starting out.

So all you need to do is use this:

```
<Match ContentType="Food">
    <Match DisplayType="Summary">
        <Place Parts_Common_Metadata_Summary="-"/>
    </Match>
</Match>
```

Note the Parts_Common_Metadata**_Summary**

Comment: thanks that is very helpful. Is there any reason that you would need the `<Match DisplayType="Summary"> in this case? Would the code work exactly the same in both cases, or would there be situations where they would work differently?

Comment: In this case your wouldn't need the match segment. But you may use the summary display shape in a different display type (not summary or detail) where you may need the match segment